# Getting SSH output into StreamReader from long running SSH commands

Tags: c#, .net, ssh

I’m attempting to capture output from a long running `SSH` command that may take a few seconds to initially produce any text output once called and may take up to a minute to fully complete.

The below code snippet works fine if I issue a simple command to execute such as `ls` that produces immediate output into the output stream.

However, I get nothing returned and `SSH` disconnects if I run a command that doesn’t instantly produce any output.

```
using (var sshClient = new SshClient(target, 22, userName, password))
{
    sshClient.Connect();
    var cmd = sshClient.CreateCommand(command);
    var result = cmd.BeginExecute();

    using (var reader = new StreamReader(cmd.OutputStream))
    {
        while (!reader.EndOfStream || !result.IsCompleted)
        {
            string line = reader.ReadLine();
            if (line != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }
        sshClient.Disconnect();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BeginExecute` begins an asynchronous command execution. You need to wait and keep reading the output stream until it completes.

In a simple way,

```
        using (var sshClient = new SshClient(host, 22, username, password)) {
            sshClient.Connect();
            var cmd = sshClient.CreateCommand("for i in `seq 1 10`; do sleep 1; echo $i; done");
            var asyncResult = cmd.BeginExecute();
            var outputReader = new StreamReader(cmd.OutputStream);
            string output;
            while (!asyncResult.IsCompleted) {
                output = outputReader.ReadToEnd();
                Console.Out.Write(output);
            }
            output = outputReader.ReadToEnd();
            Console.Out.Write(output);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm getting the expected results now.